# how to define 2 config upload file in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, upload, config

I want to upload 2 file with 2 config section but first file don't work and second file work good for me.  how can i find problem in this code.

Please help me.
This is my code :

```
$this->load->library('upload');

    $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/images/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']      = '200';
    $config['max_width']     = '200';
    $config['max_height']    = '200';
    $config['file_name']     = time();

    $this->upload->initialize($config); // Important
    if ($this->upload->do_upload('logo')) { 

        $logo = $this->upload->data(); 

    } elseif ($this->input->post('logo')) { 

        $logo['file_name'] =  $this->input->post('logo');

    } else {
        $logo['file_name'] = '';    
    }

    //===================================================

    $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/images/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']      = '200';
    $config['max_width']     = '950';
    $config['max_height']    = '250';
    $config['file_name']     = time();

    $this->upload->initialize($config); // Important
    if ($this->upload->do_upload('header')) { 

        $header = $this->upload->data(); 

    } elseif($this->input->post('header')) {

        $header['file_name'] =  $this->input->post('header');   

    } else { 
        $header['file_name'] = ''; 
    }
```

Comment: How is your time() variable generated? It's possible that they are given the same file name and thus the second file upload overwrites the first.

Comment: Oh, do you have solution ?

Comment: Yes, make your filenames more dynamic! I have a feeling that if you output the values of `$config['file_name']` for both files, they will be the same. You should try and make the file names so they incorporate the original file name, a time stamp, then a random number just to be safe.

Comment: I chage it to : $config['encrypt_name']  = true; But not work

Comment: I found my problem, Codeigniter can't upload png files. for more detail, you can see this article : http://www.genuinescope.com/blog/2012/06/codeigniter-upload-gives-error-file-type-not-allowed-for-png-images/

Comment: Before initializing your upload library for the second time you need to redefine the `$config = array` array as a blank array. I faced the same problem once. For example in the second time your initialization should look like: `$config  = array();$config['upload_path']   = './uploads/images/';$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';$config['max_size']      = '200';$config['max_width']     = '950';$config['max_height']    = '250';$config['file_name']     = time();$this->upload->initialize($config); // Important`